# Automate service (couchbase) configuration of a docker container

Tags: docker, couchbase

I think i'm missing some Docker concept here.

I want to make some initial configuration in the couchbase:

- Create a bucket
- Set admin password

I've added the couchbase-cli commands in the Dockerfile, but when the RUN instructions are executed after the CMD, the couchbase service is not available at build time.

What is the best approach to automate configuration of the couchbase service?

Here it is the complete Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

MAINTAINER Couchbase Docker Team <docker@couchbase.com>

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq runit wget python-httplib2  && \
    apt-get autoremove && apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV CB_VERSION=4.1.0 \
    CB_RELEASE_URL=http://packages.couchbase.com/releases \
    CB_PACKAGE=couchbase-server-enterprise_4.1.0-ubuntu12.04_amd64.deb \
    CB_SHA256=38b92711a52cbb0f8d4ab977e0ea2fb4e25022a0660dacc26fd7a60031eb70d2 \
    PATH=$PATH:/opt/couchbase/bin:/opt/couchbase/bin/tools:/opt/couchbase/bin/install \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/couchbase/lib

# Create Couchbase user with UID 1000 (necessary to match default
# boot2docker UID)
RUN groupadd -g 1000 couchbase && useradd couchbase -u 1000 -g couchbase -M

# Install couchbase
RUN wget -N $CB_RELEASE_URL/$CB_VERSION/$CB_PACKAGE && \
    echo "$CB_SHA256  $CB_PACKAGE" | sha256sum -c - && \
    dpkg -i ./$CB_PACKAGE && rm -f ./$CB_PACKAGE

# Add runit script for couchbase-server
COPY scripts/run /etc/service/couchbase-server/run

# Add bootstrap script
COPY scripts/entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["couchbase-server"]

RUN couchbase-cli cluster-init -c localhost:8091 \
    --cluster-username=admin --cluster-password=test --cluster-init-ramsize=600  \
    -u Administrator -p password

RUN couchbase-cli bucket-create -c localhost:8091 -u admin -p test  --bucket=web-chat \
      --bucket-type=couchbase  \
      --bucket-port=11222  \
      --bucket-ramsize=500  \
      --bucket-replica=1

EXPOSE 8091 8092 8093 11207 11210 11211 18091 18092
VOLUME /opt/couchbase/var
```

The error happens when i try run the couchbase-cli is the the line, because the couchbase service is not available at build time:

```
 Step 12 : RUN couchbase-cli cluster-init -c localhost:8091     --cluster-username=admin --cluster-password=mtd123 --cluster-init-ramsize=600      -u Administrator -p password
 ---> Running in 0cd5228e8443
ERROR: command: cluster-init: localhost:8091, [Errno 111] Connection refused
ERROR: Service 'couchbase' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c couchbase-cli cluster-init -c localhost:8091     --cluster-username=admin --cluster-password=mtd123 --cluster-init-ramsize=600      -u Administrator -p password' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: "an error" – what error?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Updated with the error. Thank you!

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but the error message indicates that the couchbase-server you are trying to connect to doesn't run. It seems like you expect `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` to be executed by the point you are issuing the `couchbase-cli` `RUN` statements. This would be a wrong assumption -- they are only executed when you actually start the container.

Comment: I've improved the description of what i'm trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: Ran into a similar issue trying to dockerize community-4.0.0. Even put sleep to wait, but nothing works. Just get connection refused error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is happening because Couchbase is not running. You could run these in the same RUN step you have installed it.

```
RUN wget -N $CB_RELEASE_URL/$CB_VERSION/$CB_PACKAGE && \
    echo "$CB_SHA256  $CB_PACKAGE" | sha256sum -c - && \
    dpkg -i ./$CB_PACKAGE && rm -f ./$CB_PACKAGE && \
    couchbase-cli cluster-init -c localhost:8091 \
    --cluster-username=admin --cluster-password=test --cluster-init-ramsize=600  \
    -u Administrator -p password
```

Comment: Got it! Maybe a better question could be: How to RUN a command after service initialization?

Because on build, the service is not up. The service becames available just when the container is created and up, right? 

In my case, i need to run those commands just once after the container is up to initiate the database configuration.

Comment: But the entrypoint runs on every container start, don't ? For my use case i need to run it just once.

Comment: You could run this only when some docker environment variable is set.

Comment: Run script on start. Example [Github](https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase-bucket)